# Swift UIScrollView - Correct Implementation for Only Vertical Scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout

In advance, I apologize as I would say that I'm a beginner with iOS programming.

I want to use `UIScrollView` because the content to display exceed the height of the screen.
Therefore, I would like only a vertical scroll and not a horizontal scrolling.

I'm using the Storyboard to draw the views with `AutoLayout`.

Here's are the screenshot of my `UIViewController` with the `UIScrollView` :

[image]
[image]

Then I change the Label to a big text like that

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.label1Label.text = "Seize jours après la chute du président Blaise Compaoré, le Burkina Faso a un nouveau chef d'EtatA l'issue d'ultimes tractions, civils et militaires se sont accordés, lundi 17 novembre, sur le nom du diplomate Michel KafandoSeize jours après la chute du président Blaise Compaoré, le Burkina Faso a un nouveau chef d'EtatA l'issue d'ultimes tractions, civils et militaires se sont accordés, lundi 17 novembre, sur le nom du diplomate Michel Kafando"
    self.label1Label.numberOfLines = 0
    self.label1Label.sizeToFit()
```

My problem is that if I don't set manually a width for my contentView (inside the `UIScrollView`), the scrolling is horizontal, not vertical. (Look Screenshot below):

[image]

I've tried to set contentSize as I've seen in many google post but without success :

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400.0, 600.0)
```

If I set a width manually for my contentview (`i.e : 320pts`), the scrolling will be vertical (GOOD) but then depending on the iphone size, it won't cover the whole width of the screen as shown in the following screenshot :

[image]

The question is : what is the correct implementation to use `UIScrollView` to have a `contentView` that respect the autolayout constraint (`full screen  : 0top - 0bottom - 0left - 0right`) and the scrolling to be only vertical.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Mike Woelmer shows how to do this correctly with Interface Builder on the Atomic Object blog.

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/

I also have my own code only (no storyboard implementation) on github.

https://github.com/nadthevlad/AutolayotScrollview

You don't want to set the height or width of your content or views. 
Instead you want to use Autolayouts pins and constraints to set how the scrollview behaves.

1. Create your UIScrollView *scrollView.
2. You want to create one UIView *contentView which you will put the rest of your view elements into.

   ```
   [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
   [scrollView addSubview:contentView];
   [contentView addSubview:_label1];
   [contentView addSubview:_label2];
   [contentView addSubview:_label3];
   [contentView addSubview:_label4];
   [contentView addSubview:_label5];
   [contentView addSubview:_label6];
   ```
3. Pin the 4 edges of scrollView to the 4 edges of self.view
4. Pin the top and bottom edges of contentView to the top and bottom of scrollView.
5. This is the tricky part.  To set the horizontal sizing, you want the leading (right) and trailing(left) edges of the contentView to be pinned to the leading and trailing edges self.view instead of scrollView.  Even though contenView is a sub view of scrollView its horizontal constraints are going to reach outside of the scrollView and connect to self.view.
6. Pin any other view elements to contentView as you normally would.

Comment: You don't have to include all your view elements into one view. That's not necessary. The key is to make sure that the constraints can specify the dimension of the scrollable content. From Apple tech note: "The constraints on the subviews of the scroll view must result in a size to fill, which is then interpreted as the content size of the scroll view. " Link to tech note: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: horizontal sizing in step number 5 could be solved by setting ContentView width equal to ScrollView width. it could be done in IB

Comment: I was able to solve it by setting the 4 edges of contentView to scrollView in step 4, and in step 5, setting the width of contentView to that of `self.view`

Comment: Followed the steps exactly and it hit the nail on the head.  Also remember to add a fixed height for the content view and set that height to be greater than the height of the device to test the scrolling.

Comment: For me in addition to this list I had to set the content view to have a y value (ie center vertically) and also had to pin the trailing edge to the scrollview. Without pinning trailing edge it complained about ambiguous scroll.

Answer (score 23):

The trick to permitting a UIScrollView to scroll in only one direction is to make the content size of the UIScrollView for the restricted dimension the same as the size of the UIScrollView's frame in the same dimension. So in this case, `scrollview.contentSize.width` should equal `scrollview.frame.size.width`.

With that in mind, try the following:

1. Ensure you have constraints set up in the same way as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23847273/2042512)
2. Add the following code to your view controller:

   ```
   override func viewWillLayoutSubviews()
   {
       super.viewWillLayoutSubviews();
       self.scrollView.contentSize.height = 3000; // Or whatever you want it to be.
   }
   ```

Personally, I'm really not a fan of Auto Layout. If you are interested in trying this without Auto Layout - ie. just with code instead of constraints - you could turn off Auto Layout for the view controller's view and change your `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method to look like this:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews()
{
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews();

    self.scrollView.frame = self.view.bounds; // Instead of using auto layout
    self.scrollView.contentSize.height = 3000; // Or whatever you want it to be.
}
```

Comment: Thanks this did the trick for me after some attempts to fix this!

Comment: The trick is to calculate the size on `viewWillLayoutSubviews `!

Answer (score 7):

This how I always do it for scrolling vertically from storyboard with constraints :

1-drag a viewcontroller

2-drag a scrollview in the controller's main view with constraints L=0 , T =0 , T =0 and B = 0 to its superview (controller's main view).

3-drag a UIVIew into the scroll view to work as its content view with constraints L-0,T=0,T=0,B=0 to its superview(the scrollview)

- well here its time for setting Content size of scroll view , which controls  scrolling both Horizontally and vertically as follows.

4-for stoping horizontal scrolling , make content view equal width to scrollview with constraint.

5-make height of content view equal hight  of controller's view , This is **temporary** *till we fill it with scrollable content* .

6-add controls in the content view  till finish .

7-and the most important delete the constraint you made in point 5 of the hight of content view  and instead of it make constraint from the control on bottom of content view  to have bottom alignment to it . This helps in making content view hight starts from first control on top and down till last control (it is all depends on this step).

8-just run and results should be as expected , otherwise please let me know .

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot it works perfectly! When developing, you can directly skip step 5 (the scroll and controls don't work but you can build the app)

Answer (score 2):

You can define ScrollView normally and constrain the properties of ScrollView normally

```
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .white
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

    scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
```

But the trick is in how you define your Label (or other view) that may be wider than the screen.
Instead of using

```
myLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor, constant: -10.0).isActive = true
```

You should use

```
myLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -10.0).isActive = true
```

This second line will stop that view from causing horizontal scrolling.  Do that with all your subviews and you won't scroll horizontally.  (It will still scroll vertically as planned.)

Also, don't forget to set the bottom constraint on your last subview to make sure your UIScrollview scrolls vertically.

```
labelX.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10.0).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @NadtheVlad, I finally saw the light. Some further fiddling taught me that contentView just needs to be pinned to scrollView's Top, Bottom and Width. No need to reference self.view.

With [EasyPeasy](https://github.com/nakiostudio/EasyPeasy), this is simply:

```
scrollView <- Edges()
contentView <- [Top(), Bottom(), Width().like(scrollView)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**I am late..  if you give the width constrains of label equal to view then you can achieve same kind of thing**

```
 aboutCaption.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor , multiplier: 0.9).isActive = true
```

**here is my sample code**

```
class AboutVC: UIViewController{

let scrollView = UIScrollView()

lazy var aboutLbl : UILabel = {
    let lbl = UILabel()
    lbl.text = "About"
    lbl.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 19)
    return lbl
}()

lazy var aboutCaption : UILabel = {
    let lbl = UILabel()
    lbl.text = "Hi. My name is Uzumaki Naruto. I am a professional MMA Coach with 15+ years of experience. I specialize in ninjutsu, shadow clones and various other techniques. I am in the TOP50 coaches in the Sports category. Been with GIGIMOT for 5 years already. Not a single bad review. "
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0
    lbl.font  = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue Thin", size: 16)!
    lbl.textColor = .systemGray2
    return lbl
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureUI()
    //        tableView.dataSource = self
    //        tableView.delegate = self
}

func configureUI() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    
    //Add and setup scroll view
    self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .white
    self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    self.scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true;
    self.scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true;
    self.scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true;
    self.scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true;
    
    scrollView.addSubview(aboutLbl)
    
    aboutLbl.anchor(top: scrollView.topAnchor, left: scrollView.leftAnchor , paddingTop: 10 , paddingLeft: 10)
    
    
    scrollView.addSubview(aboutCaption)
    aboutCaption.anchor(top: aboutLbl.bottomAnchor, left: scrollView.leftAnchor, bottom: scrollView.bottomAnchor , right: scrollView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 10, paddingBottom: 10, paddingRight: 0)
    aboutCaption.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor , multiplier: 0.9).isActive = true
    
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The exact answer for 2023:

### Vertical example:

```
var scroll: UIScrollView
var tall: UIView // some tall view, imagine a few screen heights.
```

1. Fix the size of `scroll` with top/right/bottom/left constraints to it's superview.
2. Make `tall` a subview of `scroll`.
3. **Believe it or not**, for `tall` set ***bottom, top and width*** EQUAL to its superview (ie, scroll).

That's all there is to it.

---

Don't forget to, obviously, inherently set the height of the `tall`. (For example, if it is 10 labels, obviously hook those up so that `tall` height is set by those, or whatever it is you're doing in `tall`. Don't forget to `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` of course.

Answer (score -1):

I use this implementation for only horizontal/vertical scrollviews, although it is in Objective-C, I will try to explain the logic if something is unclear to you.

```
//Getting iDevice's screen width
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

//Setting the right content size - only height is being calculated depenging on content.
CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth, HEIGHT_OF_YOUR_CONTENT);
self.scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;
```

Now the width of the contentSize property of the scrollview is being attached to the actual width of the device's screen, so the scrollview will be scrolling only in vertical direction.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried your solution, but the contentSize doesn't seem to affect the UIScrollView. Would you happen to understand why ?

Comment: As I understand, this is a tutorial code, could you upload the project here?