# Disabling Horizontal Scrolling from UIScrollView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

**Scroll View**

I have a UIScrollView, with constraints `left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0`

**Inside Scroll View**

At the top of this `UIScrollView` is a `UIImageView` with constraints `left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, height: 200`

Underneath this I have a `UITextView` with constraints `left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0`

This means the `UITextView` will resize with respect to its content, and I set the `scrollingEnabled` to `false` for the `UITextView`.

So, when I run, it *almost* works perfectly.

The one problem is the `UIImageView` takes up about 10% more than the actual screen width. Hence, horizontal scrolling is enabled.

I have tried adding the lines

```
imageView.frame = CGRect(0, 0, screenSize.width, 200)
scrlView.contentSize.width = screenSize.width
```

but this makes no difference. I can still scroll horizontally and the Image View still takes up around 10% more than the actual screen width.

Note, I have not set imageView screen width in storyboard, only programatically.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do this `scrlView.contentSize.width = 0;`

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326924/swift-uiscrollview-correct-implementation-for-only-vertical-scrolling

Comment: I met same issue many times in the past. I solved my problem with using contentview in scrollView. I advice use uiview as contentview in scrollView. The fundamental point is width of contentView should be equal scrollView's width. All your imageview textview etc must be in content view.

Comment: Normally the scrollview won't scroll if the `contentsize.width <= width` of the scrollview, so if you don't want to do any calculation, safely set the `contentsize.width = 0;` that will eliminate the scroll for sure.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Like this,

**Swift 4.0**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x>0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
    }
}
```

And, you can set this property:

```
scrollImg.isDirectionalLockEnabled = true
```

Comment: perfect, it worked with the first function. what does the `directionLockEnabled` do?

Comment: Actually, the scrolling has stopped, but the imageView is still too large

Comment: You should add `scrollView.contentOffset.x < 0` too, otherwise good answer.

Comment: I have only one problem with this solution. When I try to scroll horizontally, it won't scroll but it will also block vertical scrolling for about a second. Does anybody know a solution for this?

Comment: This should definitely be HunterCopp's answer below ( != 0), otherwise can scroll diagonally sideways (up/down).

Comment: Correct answer (Y)

Comment: It's better replace 'scrollView.contentOffset.x > 0' with 'scrollView.contentOffset.x != 0' to disable scrolling in both directions along x axis.

Answer (score 33):

**Swift 4**

Horizontal Scroll Lock

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x != 0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
    }
}
```

You can change the x to y for vertical scrolling.

Make sure to add UIScrollViewDelegate like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    ...
}
```

And set the delegate for the ScrollView

```
scrollView.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 28):

I changed this so that it just returns 0. No need to check at all if you want scroll off.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
}
```

No need for the directional lock.

Answer (score 4):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
}
```

This stops the scrollview from scrolling towards the leading edge too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storyboard and autolayout, then you should consider how ScrollView work in Storyboard with autolayout.

Consider the following.

1. Add a single view on your scrollView with constrains
   left, right, top, bottom, height, width,
2. Make the outlet of the width and height
3. Add your subViews to the view you added in the scrollView

update the width to the screenSize eg: 320 for iPhone5 or 4.

```
self.viewWidth = SCREEN_WIDTH;
[self.view updateConstraints];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
}
```

Do not use  scrollView.contentOffset.x < 0 or > 0 like others have mentioned because it will only stop scroll to one side horizontally and not both.