# How do I navigate forward and backward within UIPageViewController using buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm creating an onboarding app for New Patients of a physical therapy clinic. The new patient will answer questions on each view controller within the `UIPageViewController` and tap a button to go to the next question.

I followed a tutorial and set up my `UIPageViewController` `PageVC` along with 3 view controllers. `PageVC` currently changes pages by swiping, but I want to be able to navigate backward and forward through view controllers using two buttons that are subviews of `PageVC` itself. How do I accomplish this?

I like using `UIPageViewController` and want to understand it a bit more. If there is a more effective method besides using `UIPageViewController` to accomplish this same task I'm happy to consider it.

```
    class PageVC: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

        private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
            return [self.VCInstance(name: "BodyChart"),
                    self.VCInstance(name: "Symptoms"),
                    self.VCInstance(name: "HadSurgery")]
        }()

        private func VCInstance(name: String) -> UIViewController {
            return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
                instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
        }

        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }

            let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

            guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
                return nil
            }

            guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
                return nil
            }

            return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
        }

        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }

            let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
            let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count

            guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
                return nil
            }

            guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
                return nil
            }

            return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            dataSource = self

            if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
                setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

 }
```

Comment: Possible duplication of: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489920/ios-swift-uipageviewcontroller-turning-page-programatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489920/ios-swift-uipageviewcontroller-turning-page-programatically) But this is another way.

UIPageViewController has an instance method transition. The snippet below will move from the first to the second page child view controller.

```
pageViewController.transition(from: pageViewController.viewControllers[0], to: pageViewController.viewControllers[1], duration: 0.3, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: nil, completion: nil)
```

> PageVC currently changes pages by swiping, but I want to be able to navigate backward and forward through view controllers using two buttons

Add your buttons to page content, then disable [horizontal scrolling on PageVC's scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197630/disabling-horizontal-scrolling-from-uiscrollview-swift#32197672) or disable views' user interaction in a mannered fashion.